# Should I run as root in a contained environment?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, security, root

The windows 10 anniversary update is out, and I wanted to try out the new bash integration. I used the 'quick setup' to make a root account with no password as the Ubuntu layer has no access to the windows files. I installed the ubuntu layer as a *nix test environment in which to learn to make practical programs and use tools that are more comfortable to use from a command line (mutt, irssi, vim, git). I still have some anxiety about running as root all the time after I accidentally executed `rm -rf /tmp/tests *` as root on my old machine.

It would be more convenient to run as root all the time so I don't have to sudo, and there is no risk of making permanent damage to the system as the shell itself has no administrator access to the rest of my system or personal files. Is it acceptable to have root as the only user in this situation?

Comment: Hmmm as far as I knew bash had access to your windows files on /mnt/c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL should have access to all of your drives in /mnt/[drive letter]. Microsoft said that if you do something like `rm -r /mnt/c`, wsl will indeed proceed to wipe out your entire c drive. So... well, as long as you don't touch /mnt, you should be fine. Running `lxrun/uninstall/full/y` and then `lxrun/install/y` in cmd will reset WSL if you mess up that installation.

I personally would recommend storing project files in a folder somewhere outside of WSL and then symlinking it to some folder inside of your Ubtunu filesystem(through /mnt/foo)- that way they'll still be there should you have to reset WSL, but you don't have to interact directly with the Windows filesystem very often.

Oh, and another note- if you DO break WSL with your magical root privilages, you can access he filesystem through C:\Users[you]\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs. You won't be able to change anything(that'll just break stuff even more), but this can be used to recover files.

One more thing- note that some programs in Linux don't like being run as root, so have another user handy